# Why all NP-complete problems can be reducible to 3-SAT?

Tags: np, np-complete, sat

When I tried to figure out why halting-problem is NP-hard, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990683/proof-that-the-halting-problem-is-np-hard).
However, there is a statement confuse me

> We begin by noting that all NP-complete problems are reducible to 3SAT.

Why all NP-Complete problems can be reducible to 3-SAT?

Hope for your answer :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, an **NP**-complete problem X has the property that every problem Y ∈ **NP** reduces to X. (This is what **NP**-hardness means.) Similarly, by definition every **NP**-complete problem is in **NP**. Putting these two together, every **NP**-complete problem reduces to every other, so all **NP**-complete problems reduce to 3SAT.

Comment: is there a resource showing reductions from common NP-Complete problems to 3SAT?  Ie. clique, vertex cover, independent set, subset sum, knapsack

Comment: I’m not familiar with a standardized resource for doing that, but I imagine that if you search “SAT Solver” you might find some links?