# Polynomial time algorithm for a NP-hard

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NP vs NP-Complete vs NP-Hard — what does it all mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857244/np-vs-np-complete-vs-np-hard-what-does-it-all-mean)

Euler circuit problem can be easily solved in polynomial time
Hamilton circuit problem is proved to be NP-hard
nobody in the world can give a polynomial time algorithm for a NP-hard problem

What is meant by polynomial time and NP-hard? I know what is O(n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polynomial time means that there exist a constant `a`, such that the complexity of your algorithm is `O(n^a)`.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) is an explanation about `NP-hard`.

Comment: it is really difficult to understand NP-hard

Comment: For a gentler introduction, see [P versus NP Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)