# Does Reducing P or NP instance to NP-Complete make that instance also NP-Hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, analysis, np, np-complete, np-hard

If a Problem X lying in P or NP can be reduced to NP-Complete, is that problem X automatically an NP-Hard problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between NP, NP-Complete and NP-Hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857244/what-are-the-differences-between-np-np-complete-and-np-hard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick reply:** No, it does not.

Recall the definition of NP-hard problems.

> A problem *X* is NP-Hard if every problem in NP **can be polynomially
>   reduced to *X***.

If on the other hand a problem ***X* can be polynomially reduced to** some NP-complete problem *Y*, it means that *Y* is at least as hard as *X*, not the other way around.

Finally, if an NP-complete problem *Z* **can be polynomially reduced to *X***, then indeed *X* is NP-hard as every problem *W* in NP can be reduced to *Z* and by combining the two reductions we can reduce *W* to *X*, so the definition is satisfied.

**Q:** If a Problem X lying in P or NP can be reduced to NP-Complete, is that problem X automatically an NP-Hard problem?

**A:** No

**Q:** If a Problem X lying in P or NP is such that an NP-Complete problem can be reduced to it, is that problem X automatically an NP-Hard problem?

**A:** Yes