# SIP Route parameters: r2 and rpp

Tags: sip

I'm using the VoIP provider Messagenet and I see that it sends this INVITE to my client:

```
INVITE sip:me@my.ip.address;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Record-Route: <sip:212.97.59.76:5061;r2=on;lr=on;ftag=as2a6c9e96;rpp=np>
Record-Route: <sip:212.97.59.76;r2=on;lr=on;ftag=as2a6c9e96;rpp=np>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 212.97.59.76:5061;branch=z9hG4bKb812.a8e25f17.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 193.227.104.21:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1966d0a8
Max-Forwards: 69
From: "fromname" <sip:fromnumber@sip.messagenet.it>;tag=as2a6c9e96
To: <sip:mynumber@212.97.59.76>
Contact: <sip:fromnumber@193.227.104.21:5060>
Call-ID: 46cee45e062a30e3372663265a0be595@sip.messagenet.it
CSeq: 102 INVITE
User-Agent: whisky
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
X-Mnet-InLeg: whisky:1530689207.16483286;NH9HCiZ0TqZGK1ACkkhlvh67g1ig7LPEf+W5lblauyjqYqxgm1B2stIr6Mog/CC6
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 377

v=0
o=root 60186075 60186075 IN IP4 193.227.104.23
s=whisky
c=IN IP4 193.227.104.23
t=0 0
m=audio 50216 RTP/AVP 18 8 3 0 97 101
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:97 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:97 mode=30
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=maxptime:150
a=sendrecv
```

My question is: what do the parameters *r2* and *rpp* mean in the Record-Route headers?

```
Record-Route: <sip:212.97.59.76:5061;r2=on;lr=on;ftag=as2a6c9e96;rpp=np>
Record-Route: <sip:212.97.59.76;r2=on;lr=on;ftag=as2a6c9e96;rpp=np>
```

I'm looking for some documentations about this, but I have found nothing until now.

Comment: 'r2=on' means the double record-route technique is being used, as described in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5658#section-5

Comment: For 'rpp=np' you might want to lookup 'rural postman problem' and 'np-hard'. It has to do with the minimal cost to travel a certain part of a network.

Comment: On 'np' you can find a good description here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857244/what-are-the-differences-between-np-np-complete-and-np-hard